# .NET 8 and Domain-Driven Design - error "Ambiguous match found"

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture, .net-8.0

I am try to create a .NET 8 app using domain-driven design and Clean Architecture patterns following Amichai Mantinband Youtube tutorial.

But I get an error

> Ambiguous match found for 'CBTSystem.Domain.Common.Models.AggregateRoot`2[CBTSystem.Domain.Entities.ValueObjects.UserId,System.String] CBTSystem.Domain.Common.Models.AggregateRootId`1[System.String] Id'.

whenever I try to fetch a `User`.

This is my code - my `ValueObject`:

```
public abstract class ValueObject:IEquatable<ValueObject>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents();

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is null || obj.GetType()!=GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        var valueObject = (ValueObject)obj;

        return GetEqualityComponents()
                  .SequenceEqual(valueObject.GetEqualityComponents());
    }

    public static bool operator==(ValueObject left, ValueObject right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator!=(ValueObject left, ValueObject right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
  
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetEqualityComponents()
                  .Select(x=>x is not null ? x.GetHashCode() : 0)
                  .Aggregate((x, y) => x ^ y);
    }

    public bool Equals(ValueObject? other)
    {
        return Equals((object?)other);
    }
}
```

`BaseEntity` class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<TId> : IEquatable<BaseEntity<TId>>, IHasDomainEvents where TId:ValueObject
{
    private readonly List<IDomainEvent> _domainEvents=[];
    public TId Id{get; protected set;}
    public IReadOnlyList<IDomainEvent> DomainEvents => _domainEvents.AsReadOnly();

    protected BaseEntity(TId id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public void AddDomainEvent(IDomainEvent domainEvent)
    {
        _domainEvents.Add(domainEvent);
    }

    public void ClearDomainEvents()
    {
        _domainEvents.Clear();
    }

    #pragma warning disable
    protected BaseEntity() { }
    #pragma warning restore

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return obj is BaseEntity<TId> entity && Id.Equals(entity.Id);
    }

    public bool Equals(BaseEntity<TId>? other)
    {
       return other is BaseEntity<TId> entity && Id.Equals(entity.Id);
    }

    public static bool operator==(BaseEntity<TId> left, BaseEntity<TId> right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator!=(BaseEntity<TId> left, BaseEntity<TId> right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (GetType().ToString() + Id).GetHashCode();
       // return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

`AggregateRootId` class:

```
public abstract class AggregateRootId<TId>:ValueObject
{
    public abstract TId Value{get; protected set;}
}
```

`AggregateRoot` class:

```
public abstract class AggregateRoot<TId, TIdType> : BaseEntity<TId> where TId : AggregateRootId<TIdType>
{
    public new AggregateRootId<TIdType> Id { get; protected set; }

    protected AggregateRoot(TId id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    #pragma warning disable
    protected AggregateRoot() { }
    #pragma warning restore
}
```

Strongly typed `UserId` class:

```
public sealed class UserId : AggregateRootId<string>
{
    public override string Value { get; protected set; }

    private UserId(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    private static UserId CreateUnique() => new(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
  
    public static UserId Create(string value) => new (value);

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Value;
    }
}
```

`User` class:

```
public sealed class User:AggregateRoot<UserId,string>
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public string ProgrammeCode { get; private set; }
    public string UserRole { get; private set; }

    private User(UserId userId, string userName, string fullName, string email, string password, 
                 string programmeCode, string userRole) : base(userId)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        FullName = fullName;
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
        ProgrammeCode = programmeCode;
        UserRole = userRole;
    }

    #pragma warning disable
    private User() : base(default!) { }   //private Test():base(default!)
    #pragma warning restore

    public static User Create(string userId, string userName, string fullName, string email, string password, 
                              string programmeCode, string userRole)
    {
        string _userId;

        if (userId is null)
        {
            _userId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            _userId = userId;
        }

        return new User(UserId.Create(_userId), userName, fullName, email, password, programmeCode, userRole);
    }

    public static void ChangePassword(string newPassword)
    {
        //Password = newPassword;
    }
}
```